# What is the canonical way to add an entire directory to an MSI database with Wix?

Tags: wix

I need to package an entire directory into the MSI file I build with Wix.

The directory resides in a non-local (to build scripts etc) location, say `C:\path\to\baz`.

The intention is to have the directory be installed on target host (where the MSI is intended to be run) as `%ProgramFiles%\foobar\baz`, it's a dependency of the software I am developing.

Wix's `heat` program seems to be designed for this job -- harvesting the contents of the directory (`baz`) and generating a Wix source file. I run it as:

```
heat.exe dir C:/path/to/baz -gg -dr baz -srd -cg baz baz.heat.wxs
```

The problem is that `heat` prepends `SourceDir\`verbatim to the path of every file it locates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="baz" />
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="electron">
            <Component Id="cmp9C432873A67498F6C219E9E15596F0D8" Directory="baz" Guid="33D27AF6-A2E4-459C-818B-876268705883">
                <File Id="filE773982796F85DF928701AF071140DE5" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll" />
            </Component>
            <!-- Other Component and nested File elements omitted. -->
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
<Wix>
```

I am not sure why it does that, I know there are some things like binder variables and other kinds of variables too, but regardless, Wix linker won't assemble the MSI because it cannot source the files specified in the generated source XML file:

```
baz.heat.wxs(12) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'SourceDir\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll'
```

I am linking both the source file generated by `heat` like above, and what I'd call my "main" source file which actually defines the feature that is installed and where the `baz` directory will be installed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Name="Foobar" Manufacturer="Acme" Id="2c05b2af-3adf-4901-b126-5a839c67978d" UpgradeCode="6db7d46b-5152-4e67-9615-c3f3c4dc205c" Language="1033" Codepage="1252" Version="7.0.0">
        <Package Id="*" Description="Acme Foobar Installer" Languages="1033" SummaryCodepage="1252" Compressed="yes" InstallerVersion="200" Keywords="Installer" Manufacturer="Acme" />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Foobar">
                    <Directory Id="baz" Name="baz" />
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id="lanthir" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="baz" />
        </Feature>
</Product>
```

I would like to know:

- Is `SourceDir` anything else but verbatim directory reference?
- What is the canonical way to make either `heat` generate proper path that can be linked as-is without issues or make the linker tool (`light`) resolve the path as generated by `heat` by default?

I have a feeling I am solving an incredibly simple and common problem and there should be a very well known and obvious solution to this. I would prefer to provide a variable to the linker so that I don't have to re-generate the source file whenever the actual path of the directory I need to embed, changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the -var command line switch on heat.  That will replace the SourceDir with $(var.WhateverYouPutAfterTheVarArg) instead.

for example

```
heat.exe dir C:/path/to/baz -gg -dr baz -srd -cg baz -var var.BazDir baz.heat.wxs
```

should result in something more like

```
<File Id="filE773982796F85DF928701AF071140DE5" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.BazDir)\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll" />
```

You then need to set a value for BazDir.  I tend to do it by updating the wixproj file

```
  <PropertyGroup>
     <ProjectDefineConstants>BazDir=PathToBazDirectory;$(ProjectDefineConstants)</ProjectDefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```